# CSS path got changed when using rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache

I am using below rewrite rule in htaccess for URL redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./blog.php?id=$1
```

In the blog.php file, i have used csspath like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

If i enter http://www.example.com/blog.php?id=1  it is working fine.

But if i enter url http://www.example.com/users/
the css path changed to

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="users/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

How can it rectified?

Comment: You could probably do a negative lookahead in your regex to make sure the value after `users` isn't `css`

Comment: Did you try the href without the dot? Like: /css/default.css

Comment: I tried both but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule before your other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js)($|/) - [L]
```

This will end the rewriting process.